# Overwrite only last default argument in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I am using [canvas2image](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image) for downloading screenshot of my webpage.I want to override the defaultfile name of the downloaded image.It is the last argument for the function that downloads image.

The function that writes image

```
return {
        saveAsImage: saveAsImage,
        saveAsPNG: function (canvas, width, height, fileName) {
            return saveAsImage(canvas, width, height, 'png',fileName);
        },
```

So here I overwritten the default filename with desired fileName as follows

My function to save image

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#target"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // Convert and download as image 
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas,fileName = 'Calendar.png');
        }
    });
});
```

But still it downloads the image with default name which is Date.now() according to documentation

```
if (type == undefined) { type = 'png'; }
            filename = filename == undefined||filename.length === 0 ?Date.now()+'.'+type: filename+'.'+type
```

Also I am not using the latest library from github page but the library defined at this [link](https://superal.github.io/canvas2image/canvas2image.js)
Please go over this link to find actual library I am using.I think in latest version they have removed the fileName argument(I was using latest initially and then image was downloading with "download" as name without any extension as well)

Comment: You shouldn't expect people to go searching through a provided link to find what you're referencing. You should include everything you can in the question itself. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas,100,100,'png','Calendar.png');`

Comment: @peteb Sorry for providing a big long list, that was just for reference.The necessary things are in the question itself(atleast what i feel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling a function, you need to provide all required paremeters.

So instead of

```
Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas,fileName = 'Calendar.png');
```

do:-

```
Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas,100,100,'png','Calendar.png');
```

***Note:-*** you need to change width and height according to your wish

Comment: I want it to be default I mean what ever the html element has.Just want to change the name